# Automatic text correction in a normal TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, string, events, autocorrect

I want to implement an auto correction in some of the `TextBox`es  in my application. What I mean by that is when user enters a text, after a few seconds, the text should be passed to method, get corrected and passed back to the text box.

At the moment I have a very basic procedure for the correction. My TextBoxes are supposed to get a measurement value from user (Such as `1.25 mA`, `1.25uA`, `.666   A`).

Imagine I have the correction method called `CorrectValue`:

```
private void CorrectValue(TextBox tb)
{
   tb.Text = tb.Text.Trim().Remove('', string.Empty);
   //Actual correction is going to be much more complicated
}
```

So what would be the best approach fo doing so? what kind of events should be rised? how to count the seconds user spent writing in the TextBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a **silverlight** user control i made (it's an extract from actual production code, works flawlessly) which does exactly what you need: react to input with a certain delay. it uses events to mimic "textchanged". Adapting it to windows forms is straightforward.

```
public partial class DelayedTextBox : UserControl
{
    private DispatcherTimer eventTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    public double TextChangedDelay
    {
        get { return eventTimer.Interval.TotalMilliseconds; }
        set { eventTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(value); }
    }

    public delegate void DelayedTextChangedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
    public event DelayedTextChangedHandler DelayedTextChange;

    private object relayedSender = null;
    private RoutedEventArgs relayedE = null;

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return PlainTextBox.Text;
        }

        set
        {
            PlainTextBox.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? string.Empty : value;
        }
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public TimedTextChangedTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TextChangedDelay = 500;
        eventTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(eventTimer_Tick);
    }

    private void StartTimer(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        relayedSender = sender;
        relayedE = e;
        eventTimer.Start();
    }

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        eventTimer.Stop();
        relayedSender = null;
        relayedSender = null;
    }

    private void eventTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StopTimer();
        if (DelayedTextChange != null)
            DelayedTextChange(relayedSender, relayedE);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!maskedInput)
            ReactToInput(sender, e);
    }

    private void ReactToInput(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!eventTimer.IsEnabled)
        {
            StartTimer(sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            StopTimer();
            StartTimer(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

you can use the control the exact same way you normally use a TextBox. subscribe to its `DelayedTextChange` event to react to user input.

Answer (score 2):

The best place for validating the input is the event `Validating` of the TextBox control. If the entered value isn't valid, set `e.Cancel` in that event to false.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the best event for such corrections / input validating is the `Validating` event.

Problem with TextChanged is, it occurs while typing and you can't be sure the user has completed his input.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic implementation would be for you to use the TextChanged event of the Textbox. In this event you can your method CorrectValue(). As a parameter for the function you can cast the 'sender' parameter of the event to TextBox and pass it on to your method.

**Edit:**
For counting the time you could set a Timer and fire it every 0.5second for example. After, let's say, 2 seconds you call the Correction method. For example:

```
private int _ticks;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_ticks++ == 4)
    {
        //Call correction method
        timer1.Stop();
        _ticks = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: TextChanged is not that good place. It occurs on every entered character and will produce perhaps unvalid values. e.g. The user has to enter a number and a measurement unit. After entering "1" TextBox.Changed is raised and the check routine will state this as an error, because measurement is missing.

Comment: You are certainly right, but it is the most basic implementation he could use.. :)

Comment: Don't force people to use timers, that's ugly.

Comment: Then how will he count the time a user is editing in the textbox? Another solution would be to call the correction method only after a certain amount of characters have been typed in.. But how should he do it then if he really wants it to depend on time?

Comment: As others mentioned, its "ugly" to force people on timers and to me it also doesn't make sense to check an input which possibly isn't even compleded. So why do this 'hack' as opposed to just trigger the correction in a Validating' event.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a really old post, but anyone looking for a simplified implementation may get some use out of the following:

[image]

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private Dictionary<string, string> AutoCorrectDictionary => 
    File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\AutoCorrect.txt").ToDictionary(ln => ln.Split('|')[0], ln => ln.Split('|')[1]);

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cur = textBox1.SelectionStart;
    var match = new Regex(@"[^\s]+\s$").Match(textBox1.Text.Substring(0, cur)).Value;
    if (!AutoCorrectDictionary.ContainsKey(match.Trim().ToLower())) return;
    var replaceTxt = $@"{AutoCorrectDictionary[match.Trim().ToLower()]} ";
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(cur - match.Length, match.Length)
        .Insert(cur - match.Length, replaceTxt);
    textBox1.SelectionStart = cur + (replaceTxt.Length - match.Length);
}
```

The dictionary I used for this example ("C:\AutoCorrect.txt") includes 970 entries of key/value pairs separated by a '|', but you could use whatever you like. In practice, I stick the `AutoCorrectDictionary()` in a static class that gets populated on startup. I did it the way I did here so that it would be clear what `AutoCorrectDictionary()` was.

Enjoy!